# Error on creating property from other class in another class

Tags: c#

Why am I getting this error?

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UserQuery.Director'

I am getting this on:

> m.DirectorName= "Someone";

Here is where it happens:

```
void Main()
{
    Movie m = new Movie();
    m.Name = "Matrix";
    m.DirectorName = "Someone";
    Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
}

public class Director
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
    
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Director DirectorName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: DirectorName is of type Director - not a string - you can't assign a string to Director type

Comment: This is a trivial error and won't be useful to future readers. It can thus be closed under the "typo / unrepro" official reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectorName is not a string. So you can't assign a string to it. You can assign a Director to it. Since DirectorName property actually represents a Director, it's poorly named. Change your movie class to this:

```
public class Movie
{
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public Director MovieDirector { get; set; }
}
```

And your method code to this:

```
 //Create a movie and set the name property
 Movie m = new Movie();
 m.Name = "Matrix";

 //Create a director and set the name property
 Director d = new Director();
 d.Name = "Someone";

 //Assign the director to the movie by setting the MovieDirector property
 m.MovieDirector = d;

 //Print out the movie's director's name.
 Console.WriteLine(m.MovieDirector.Name);
```

---

There is also a shorthand syntax for this, using object initializers:

```
Movie m = new Movie
{
    Name = "Matrix",
    MovieDirector = new Director { Name = "Someone" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`DirectorName`  is a type of `Director`,you are trying to pass string  value to it.

Answer (score -1):

In your class movie you have a reference to a class. If you want to change the string in the director class do m.DirectorName.Name

Comment: Then he'll get a NullReferenceException because he never creates `DirectorName`.